# Google analytics Calculated Metric using case when

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I am targeted to research whether this is doable:

To create a calculated metric (Order Submit) in google analytics (https://analytics.google.com/). I am using UA (not GA4). So I am going to create it in a view.

Order Submit:

- Before 2021/12/18:  [ga:eventAction] like '%Submit Button Click%'. value should be sum of [ga:uniqueEvents];
- After 2021/12/18:  [ga:eventAction] like ‘%checkout%’ and [ga:eventLabel] like ‘%2%’,value should be sum of [ga:totalEvents];

The ultimate goal is going to use the field via Google analytics API v4 in python. I know how to get the calculated metric via API once it's defined. But I couldn't figure out how to do the case statement for the calculated metric. It looks it can only handle simple operation on existing metrics, e.g. metric 1/ metric 2.

If that's not possible, any workaround?

BTW, I know in google data studio I can possibly create something like that using case statement, but it can not be used in google API v4 I suppose?

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible with calculated metric. The walkabout is to get all related dimensions and metrics in a table. Then you can calculate by yourself using SQL or whatever language depending on where you stored the data.